# How to best use multiple Tasks? (progress reporting and performance)

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I created the following code to compare images and check if they are similar. Since that takes quite a while, I tried to optimized my code using multithreading.

I worked with `BackgroundWorker` in the past and was now starting to use Tasks, but I am still not fully familiar with that.

Code below:
`allFiles` is a list of images to be compared.
`chunksToCompare` contains subset of the Tuples of files to compare (always a combination of two files to compare) - so each task can compare e. g. 20 Tuples of files.

The code below works fine in general but has two issues

- progress reporting does not really make sense, since progress is only updated when all Tasks have been completed which takes quite a while
- depending on the size of files, each thread has different processing time: in the code below it always waits until all (64) task are completed before the next is started which is obviously not optimal

Many thanks in advance of any hint / idea.

```
// List for results
List<SimilarImage> similarImages = new List<SimilarImage>();

// create chunk of files to send to a thread
var chunksToCompare = GetChunksToCompare(allFiles);

// position of processed chunks of files
var i = 0;

// number of tasks
var taskCount = 64;
while (true)
{
    // list of all tasks
    List<Task<List<SimilarImage>>> tasks = new();

    // create single tasks
    for (var n = 0; n < taskCount; n++)
    {
        var task = (i + 1 + n < chunksToCompare.Count) ?
            GetSimilarImageAsync2(chunksToCompare[i + n], threshold) : null;
        if (task != null) tasks.Add(task);
    }

    // wait for all tasks to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Where(i => i != null));

    // get results of single task and add it to list
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        if (task?.Result != null) similarImages.AddRange(task.Result);
    }

    // progress of processing
    i += tasks.Count;

    // report the progress
    progress.Report(new ProgressInformation() { Count = chunksToCompare.Count,
        Position = i + 1 });

    // exit condition
    if (i + 1 >= chunksToCompare.Count) break;
}

return similarImages;
```

**More info:** I am using .NET 6. Images are stores on a SSD. With my test dataset it took 6:30 minutes with sequential and 4:00 with parallel execution. I am using a lib which only takes the image path of two images and then compares them. There is a lot of overhead because the same image is reloaded multiple times. I was looking for a different lib to compare images, but I was not successful.

Comment: [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) may be a better fit for this

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting, .NET 6? How much did the performance improved by switching from the normal sequential execution, to the `Task`-based parallel execution?

Comment: Yes I am using .NET 6. Indeed the performance gain was less than expected - with my test data set it took 6:30 min with sequential and 4:00 with parallel execution...

Comment: What is the type of the storage device where the images are located? Is it a SSD or a classic HDD?

Comment: Are you loading each image from the storage device only once, or you are loading it multiple times, in order to compare it with multiple other images?

Comment: If you don't have many images, I'd consider loading them all first and then doing all the compares.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Images are stores on a SSD...

Comment: @StephenCleary Unfortunaltey I am using a lib which only takes the image path of two images and the compares them. But probably you are correct - there is a lot of overhead because the same image is reloaded mulitple time. I was looking for  a different lib to compare images but I was not successfull...

Comment: Is it an option to move your images to a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)? It should speed up quite a lot the loading of the images. You can find [here](https://www.geckoandfly.com/21507/ramdisk-virtual-disk-memory/) a list of free RAM drive software.

Comment: @Norbert describe what you want to do, not how you think it can be done. It's unclear what `GetSimilarImageAsync2` or `GetChunksToCompare` do. You won't benefit from a RAM drive, when all the images are loaded in memory. Nor will loading everything in memory offer any benefit - you'd have to wait for all the data to be loaded, either with the RAM drive or in-memory collections.

Comment: @Norbert knowing what the actual job is matters - you could use one (or more) tasks to load images, another to compare them, another to compress them, so while one task performs asynchronous IO, the others crunch the already loaded data. If you want to compare multiple images you'll have to come up with a way to extract the important information to avoid N^2 comparisons

Comment: @Norbert packages like ImageSharp can be used to extract features from images and compare them. Others have built on top of ImageSharp to implement such comparisons.  *Machine Learning* libraries also have to do that, a lot. OCR and face recognition includes image comparisons.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess probably the key is that I need a more flexible lib to compare image - the one I am currently using is just taking the filename of two image. I checked ImageShare and that looks promising. So I could avoid that images are reloaded which should provide a performance increase. One more question - you said that other libs build on top of ImagesSharp to implement comparision - do you have any names that I can check?

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve? Checking two screenshots in a UI test is very different from checking two live images to see if they show the same object or scene. If you search NuGet you'll find several libraries that do the first, eg [ImageSharp.Compare](https://github.com/Codeuctivity/ImageSharp.Compare). As the repo landing page shows, it works mainly by taking the diff of the images and calculating the difference. There are several SO questions that ask how to perform image comparisons too

Comment: A  common technique you'see in similar questions is to resize to a common size, convert to grayscale so you only have to compare intensity values, and then compare using one of several techniques. For UI tests, a simple diff will tell you if any pixels are different. In other cases, edge detection is used to find the "features" of the image, then  the edge detection images are compared. In a pipeline you could have a step to resize the images, another to convert them to grayscale, another to perform edge detection etc

Comment: In the end, you can store all the grayscale or edge images in memory (depending on the algorithm you want to use) and then use Parallel.ForEach or PLINQ to execute the comparisons in parallel.

Comment: PS: I just found that ImageSharp itself has some [Image comparison classes](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/tree/e54219acec10d2d2dc247ed5fd4230204a89c07b/tests/ImageSharp.Tests/TestUtilities/ImageComparison) it uses in unit tests

Comment: Recently I posted another question that was inspired by this question: [How to compare 1,000 images using the available memory efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021712/how-to-compare-1-000-images-using-the-available-memory-efficiently)